# Ansible Fact - Accessing the additional facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am doing a little research on Ansible facts. I am accessing facts in the debug module using something like: `ansible_facts['mounts']`. I noticed there are additional facts within the dictionary like "fstype" etc. However, when I try to access this like so `ansible_facts['mounts']['fstype']` but I seems this is not the proper way to access this. I was testing a conditional with `when` to check for the fstype. Anyone know how to access this?

With everyone's help, here is the solution I came up with to assist with my research:

```
---
- name: Conditionals test
  hosts: dev

  tasks:
    - name: Update the kernel if suff space
      package:
        name: kernel
        state: latest
      loop: "{{ ansible_facts['mounts'] }}"
      when: item.mount == "/boot" and item.size_available > 20000000
```

I am looping through the ansible_facts list and checking for /boot and measuring the size. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is that you are trying to acces a list of mounts, you need to get one item from that list and get his fstype something like:

```yaml
ansible_facts['mounts'][0]['fstype']
```

Or using a loop

```yaml
- name: Print fstypes
  debug:
    var: "{{ item }}.fstype"
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
```

Comment: In Ansible v2.9 I am getting (syntax) errors and are not able to let your code snippet run. Shouldn't it be `msg: "{{ item.fstype }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"`?

Comment: Yes, thats true i post it quickly and didnt write it corretyle.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding of the data structure of Ansible facts one can use the following example and test playbook.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show amount of mounts
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ ansible_facts.mounts | type_debug }}"
        - "{{ ansible_facts.mounts | length }}"

  - name: Show mount type (sequence)
    debug:
      msg:  "{{ ansible_facts.mounts[item | int].fstype }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, ansible_facts.mounts | length) | list }}"

  - name: Show mount type (fact list)
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.fstype }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

it shows

- That `ansible_facts.mounts` is mostly a list, how to get the data type and how to get the length of it
- How to loop over a fact list `with_sequence` numbers
- How to access the list element by index number (`ansible_facts.mounts[item | int].fstype`)
- How to loop over a fact list and control the `label`

and resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show mount type (sequence)] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: vfat

TASK [Show mount type (fact list)] ******
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: ext4
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: vfat
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)
- [`with_sequence`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)
- [Adding control to loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops)

Comment: This is a pretty good example. I have not used the loop_control statement, so this is something new for me. This does get the job done and I can explore each of the variables with this method.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do this...

```
    - name: Update the kernel if suff space
      package:
        name: kernel
        state: latest
      when: ansible_facts['mounts']|selectattr('mount','equalto','/boot')|map(attribute='size_available')|first > 20000000
```

rather than looping through the mounts at all.